# What's the difference between app.master and .master pages?

Tags: 2013, theme

I've looked around and I can't seem to find the difference between an app.master page and .master pages. I'm building a new look and was wondering what the real difference is. I've found [this resource](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e09841ed-a9f9-4320-b879-c23d1b4270f1/applicationmaster-vs-defaultmaster?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy), but I can't find any other source to back it up. It's also six years old at this point, and I want to verify this is still true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. The resource you cited refers to system vs "normal" pages in SharePoint. app.master is a similar concept, used when displaying Apps. This was covered here already:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435566/set-custom-master-pages-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps